# Wireless DC motor controller circuit protection

Tags: back-emf

I'm using an off-the-shelf 2 channel wireless relay/switch to control a 12 V DC motor. The motor is attached to a wheel which can be manually turned and generate back EMF.  How should I place diodes between the motor and the controller to prevent damage to the controller circuit?

My question was badly thought out ... the circuit looks like this:
[image]

When neither relay is activated, the motor is shorted.  If the motor is turned by hand, I assume it will damage it.   How can I prevent this?

Comment: How much 'back EMF' are you expecting? Is the wireless relay/switch like this? https://www.ebay.com/itm/315mHZ-DC-12V-2-Channel-200M-Wireless-Remote-Control-Relay-Switch-Transceiver-BT/222971845984?hash=item33ea285d60:m:mmPVwnVtHESM-gMB5qhD_Ow:rk:41:pf:0

Comment: why do you think that the motor is connected to the controller circuit?